# How to subscribe to User Defined fields in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I've added on Acumatica User defined field:

[image]
How can I add to those fields CommitChanges="true" and how it's possible to add RowUpdated, FieldUpdated functionality for those fields?

Comment: Well, I think if you want to work with these fields via code, it is easier to define them in code as usual custom fields, instead of using user defined fields

Comment: Easier for sure! But that is not answer that I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These UDF fields are attribute fields that are created at runtime as part of FieldSelecting event and so can be accessed using PXCache.GetValueExt/SetValueExt as shown in the example below.  Note here that field name is prepended with a word "Attribute" followed by the attribute code.

```
        var row = Base.Opportunity.Current;
        var cache = Base.Opportunity.Cache;
        var udfREFOPP = (PXStringState)cache.GetValueExt(row, "AttributeREFOPP");
        var udfREFAPPT = (PXStringState)cache.GetValueExt(row, "AttributeREFAPPT");

        cache.SetValueExt(row, "AttributeREFOPP", udfREFAPPT.Value);
        cache.SetValueExt(row, "AttributeREFAPPT", udfREFOPP.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The UDF fields are rendered as regular fields, so the Commit Changes can be turned on from JavaScript by setting the `onValueChange` to 1.

The tricky part is with capturing the event. Unfortunately, the event is not triggered on the UDF field itself. But from the way the field is rendered it is bound to the main Form of the page. For example, on SO301000 - Sales orders it is bound to the Header form - primary view. Which means that it will trigger SO Order row level events.

[image]

From JavaScript side you can access this fields by the following way:

```
px_all.ctl00_phF_form_t1_AttributeBURDEN
```

you just need to set the onValueChange to 1 to get the Commit Changes working

```
px_all.ctl00_phF_form_t1_AttributeBURDEN.onValueChange=1;
```

As I have already explained in [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601545/6064728) the UDF's are handled via KvExt tables and to access them we need to create additional DAC.

```
[PXCacheName("SO Order Attributes")]
[Serializable]
public class SOOrderKvExt : IBqlTable
{
    public abstract class recordID : BqlGuid.Field<recordID> { }
    [PXDBGuid(IsKey = true)]
    public Guid? RecordID { get; set; }

    public abstract class fieldName : BqlString.Field<fieldName> { }
    [PXDBString(50, IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Name")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueNumeric : BqlDecimal.Field<valueNumeric> { }
    [PXDBDecimal(8)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Numeric")]
    public decimal? ValueNumeric { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueDate : BqlDateTime.Field<valueDate> { }
    [PXDBDate]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Date")]
    public DateTime? ValueDate { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueString : BqlString.Field<valueString> { }
    [PXDBString(256)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value String")]
    public string ValueString { get; set; }

    public abstract class valueText : BqlString.Field<valueText> { }
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value Text")]
    public string ValueText { get; set; }
}
```

After this we can catch the event in the SOOrder_RowUpdated handler like below:

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row is SOOrder row)
    {
        PXResultset<SOOrder> orderWithUDFs = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder, 
            LeftJoin<SOOrderKvExt, On<SOOrder.noteID, Equal<SOOrderKvExt.recordID>>,
            LeftJoin<PX.CS.CSAttribute, On<SOOrderKvExt.fieldName, Contains<PX.CS.CSAttribute.attributeID>>>>, 
            Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
            And<SOOrder.orderType,Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(this.Base, row.OrderNbr,row.OrderType);
        foreach (PXResult<SOOrder,SOOrderKvExt,PX.CS.CSAttribute> orderWithUDF in orderWithUDFs)
        {
            var udfValue = (SOOrderKvExt)orderWithUDF;
            var attributeDef = (PX.CS.CSAttribute)orderWithUDF;
            if(attributeDef.FieldName=="BURDEN")
            {
                //do something
                var value = udfValue.ValueText;//depending on the Attribute.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the same way you can work with other Row level events.
Unfortunately, I don't see any way to work with the field directly in the way we all used to do.